# XMPP server-to-server - traffic optimization?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I'm working on a design for a xmpp chat solution which involves some servers and where at least one server is connected with serious bandwidth limitations.

Assuming, we have two servers A and B, some users 0..n connected to Server A and some conferences 0..m provided by Server B.

Now assume, some users enter a conference room and a message is sent to that room. Will

1. Server B send this message once to
   Server A and Server A distributes it
   to the users or will
2. Server B send this message to each individual user of Server A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the protocol spec, [XEP 045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#message), multi-user chat messages are reflected independently to each participant.  I can't tell on a brief read if it is legal to send them server-to-server without reflecting.  However, it might be worth asking this question on an xmpp.org mailing list, where the experts tend to hang out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer and the link you provided included all I needed to know!